# Delete object in NSSet relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an object Car.h.
Car.h has carparts.h (NSSet to relationship).

I need to delete one of the parts in the NSSet belonging to car.h object.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `car.mySet` is your set, you can try it as,

```
NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [car.mySet mutableCopy];
[mutableSet removeObject:carpartsObject];
car.mySet = [mutableSet copy];
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that `Car` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject` since you have the core-data tag.

Core Data is KVO compliant.

[Reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154)
**Dynamically-Generated Accessor Methods**

By default, Core Data dynamically creates efficient public and primitive get and set accessor methods for modeled properties (attributes and relationships) of managed object classes. This includes the key-value coding mutable proxy methods such as `add<Key>Object:` and removes:, as detailed in the documentation for mutableSetValueForKey:—managed objects are effectively mutable proxies for all their to-many relationships.

Other [Reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174) about naming convention for KVO

In order to be key-value coding complaint for a `mutable unordered to-many relationship` you must implement the following methods:

`-add<Key>Object: or -add<Key>:`. At least one of these methods must be implemented. These are analogous to the NSMutableSet method addObject:.
`-remove<Key>Object: or -remove<Key>:`. At least one of these methods must be implemented. These are analogous to the NSMutableSet method removeObject:.
`-intersect<Key>:`. Optional. Implement if benchmarking indicates that performance is an issue. It performs the equivalent action of the NSSet method intersectSet:.

Comment: This is better response, then, in one line:
[car removeCarpartsObject:carpartsObject];

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the to-many object is also removed from the object storage (the default action is to nullify the parent entity), you can override one of the auto-generated methods of `Car`:

```
- (void)removeCarpartsObject:(Carpart *)value
{
    NSMutableSet *set = [self mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(carparts))];

    [set removeObject:value];
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternate way of deleting object in NSSet from core Data is using below. I tried this approach myself and it works also.

```
    - (void)removeCarpartsObject:(Carpart *)value
    {
       NSError *error;
       NSInteger index = [car.mySet.allObjects indexOfObject:carpartsObject];

       [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:car.mySet.allObjects[index]];
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    }
```